# Problems implementing regression neural network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, backpropagation

I've been trying for a while to implement my first regression neural network in MATLAB, following the example from figure 5.3 in page 231 from '[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)' book from C. Bishop.

In this example, a two-layer neural network has been used to implement several transformations, such as the **sin**, **square**, **heaviside** and **absolute value** functions. Hence, input and output layers do only have one neuron, whereas the hidden layer does have three of them. As mentioned in the image's title, hidden layers use **tanh** activation functions, whereas the output is linear.

The only function for which I sometimes got """close""" to (find what the apostrophes mean in the picture attached) was the sin one. The rest of them are still so far from what I aim. Shouldn't the solution work out for all the cases as in the example?

Please find both my picture and my code attached (it's a modified version of the one from [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55826-pattern-recognition-and-machine-learning-toolbox)).

```
%% INITIALIZATION
h = [3];
X = linspace(-1,1,1000);
T = sin(X*pi);

%% NEURAL NETWORK
eta = 1/size(X,2);
h = [size(X,1);h(:);size(T,1)];
L = numel(h);
W = cell(L-1,1);
for l = 1:L-1
    W{l} = randn(h(l),h(l+1)); % Should I maybe initialize this differently?
end
Z = cell(L,1);
Z{1} = X;
maxiter = 10000;
mse = zeros(1,maxiter);
%     forward
for iter = 1:maxiter
    for l = 2:L-1
        Z{l} = tanh(W{l-1}'*Z{l-1});   % 5.10, 5.49
    end
    Z{L} = W{L-1}'*Z{L-1}; % Linear output activation function
%     backward
    E = T-Z{L}; % E = dk       
    mse(iter) =  mean(dot(E,E),1);
    dW = Z{L-1}*E';
    W{L-1} = W{L-1}+eta*dW;
    for l = L-2:-1:1
        df = 1-Z{l+1}.^2;    % Derivative of tanh function
        dj = df.*(W{l+1}*E);
        dW = Z{l}*dj';    % 5.67
        W{l} = W{l}+eta*dW;
        E = dj;
    end
end
mse = mse(1:maxiter);
model.W = W;

%% RESULTS
plot(mse);
disp(['T = [' num2str(T) ']']);
W = model.W;
Y = X;
for l = 1:length(W)-1
    Y = tanh(W{l}'*Y);
end
Y = W{length(W)}'*Y;
disp(['Y = [' num2str(Y) ']']);

figure
plot(X, T, 'o');
hold on
plot(X, Y);
legend('T (target output)','Y (trained output)', 'Location', 'southeast');
hold off
```

### [image: Target output versus trained output] [image: Variation of error with the number of iterations]

As you may have already noticed, I'm far from being an expert in this field. If you know of any online course / nice reference apart from the aforementioned book where I can find some coded examples I would gladly appreciate that. Please feel free to ask or to comment whatever you may consider.

Comment: If you're looking for a basic machine learning course then Andrew Ng's Machine Learning on Coursera is a brilliant intro (and also uses MATLAB, which is not really a plus anymore). If you're looking for a course on the academic theory of neural networks (deep learning) specifically then try Geoffrey Hinton's Coursera course, I think it's called Neural Networks for Machine Learning (in Octave). Note that both those courses are fairly old so some of the contect is a little out of date, but still excellent. If you want a modern practical intro to deep learning try fast.ai (Python, AWS).

Comment: Regarding your code, I think it will be a lot easier to debug if you refactor it. Have separate functions for forward passes, back-propagation etc. If you're worried about your random initialisation try [Xavier initialisation](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization) (but I don't think this is going to be a factor in such a small network)